Free CI/CD platform for builds?
With AppCenter retiring, my team(of over 10 people) is looking for an alternative solution that can integrate with our private Github repo to create beta test builds for our React Native app, if possible with unlimited build minutes at no cost like AppCenter, or a very generous free tier.
Any suggestions much appreciated,

you can use Circle CI  or jenkins as it's free to use to create beta test builds for your app. with unlimited build minutes at no cost as you desire but you'll only pay for the server Jenkins running on, if you have something like small internal server or workstation local or somewhere just to do the functionality, then one of the two options will match your goal.
